# Using WMI to get printer logs

Tags: powershell, scripting, wmi

I'm trying to use WMI to get printer system logs from several servers. A week ago I made the following code which for some reason only works sometimes:

```
wmic /node:<servername> NTEvent WHERE "logfile='System' AND SourceName='Print' AND TimeGenerated > '20130219'" get EventCode,TimeGenerated,Message
```

This line of code sometimes will work, but the majority of the time I'm getting the following error whenever I've tried running it to get logs:

```
ERROR:
Code = 0x80020009
Description = Exception occurred.
Facility = Dispatch
```

I was wondering if anyone may know why this is occurring and if there would be a better method to rewrite my code. I've considered using the `get-wmiobject` cmdlet, however I'm not sure how to filter and get the same logs that I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. Neither uses `Get-WMIObject`.

Option 1: Get the whole event log, then filter.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System -Source Print|where-object{$_.timeGenerated -gt (get-date "2013-02-19")}|select-object eventid, timegenerated,message | Export-csv -path r:\log.csv -notypeinfo;
```

Option 2: Filter at the source

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='system';source='print';StartTime=(get-date "2013-02-19").date;}|select-object id,timecreated,message;
```

Best practice is to filter as close to the source of the data as possible ([Filter Left, Format Right](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.09.windowspowershell.aspx)), which would be option 2 in this case.

Comment: Hi alroc, is there an option to dump the logs straight into a .txt file after I've gotten it? I'm using the first option you wrote since the servers (win 2003) I'm using this for don't have Powershell.

Comment: To add to my comment, I've tried adding | ConvertTo-Csv at the end of the line to try outputting it to some kind of file where I can access all the log data.

Comment: I've added `Export-CSV` to the first solution. Adjust the path to meet your requirements. Note that multi-line messages *will* appear properly if you open in Excel, but you'll have to make the rows taller to see that.